# Check_mk check for perl plugin which is at check_mk_agent side

Tags: jenkins, nagios, check-mk

I have one perl script I want to use it as a nagios plugin. Here is the `github` location for this script https://github.com/MangeshBiradar/Check_mk/blob/master/check_jenkins_jobs.pl 
I want to use this perl script as `check_mk_agent` plugin, how do I create a `check_mk` check for this plugin?
Please someone could help me on it?
Thanks

Comment: I want to monitor jenkins jobs on host `A` where jenkins service is running. I installed check_mk_agent on host `A` and copied above plugin into following location on host `A`.
`/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/plugins/`
Nwxt, I want to display the health of each jenkins jobs(from host `A`) on host `B` which is nagios hosted machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you wrote (maybe next time re-read it and think about if it's understandable...)

Anyway, you should check the documentation on "MRPE" at http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_mrpe.html

That's an agent-side compatibility layer for vanilla Nagios checks.